# Highcharts stacked bar - add vertical column on right side

Tags: highcharts, stacked-chart

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

How to add vertical column to the right side of this chart. On left side, where fruit is listed, I need to have months and on right side I need to have sales (sum of stacked columns) and also if possible I'd like to add another vertical column next to sales.
Is this possible?

Comment: Within the same chart you can't use vertical and horizontal columns. In the fact `bar` series is nothing more than `column` series with option `chart.inverted` set to true. As `chart.inverted` can be set globally for one chart, then you can't use horiontal and vertical charts. Of course, you can use two separate charts.

Comment: create two charts? What's the use case like?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/320/
This is very close but I'd like to have right percentages to be aligned in a separate column, aligned, similar as 0, 2 and 4

Comment: As Pawel said, you need to create to separate chart, because you cannot combine vertical / horizosntal columns in the same chart.